# How to use credentials to connect to a SharePoint list using the Client Side Object Model?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

I need to write an application to update a list on a SharePoint 2010 site.

I found the "SPSite" which I can create with the URL, but I can't figure out how to specify with which user I want to connect.

The user isn't the current windows user, and the program isn't executed on the server.

I saw the possibility to give a "SPUserToken", but in my method I only have the user, the domain, and his password, so how can I generate this user(and I think that this user is unknown on the system executing the code, but known on the server).

Where can I specify that?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Since you're using the client object model, you won't be working with the [SPSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.aspx) class (which is part of the *server* object model).

Instead, you should create an instance of the [ClientContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext.aspx) class and supply your authentication credentials through its aptly-named [Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientruntimecontext.credentials.aspx) property. Then you can use it to fetch the [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.aspx) object you want to update:

```cs
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://yourserver/")) {
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
    List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Some List");
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    // Now update the list.
}
```

Comment: hi! what is "http://yourserver/"? can you please check my question below.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737059/sharepoint-foundation-2010-client-object-model-authentication.Thanks

Comment: is somehting for JSOM?

Comment: ClientContext is not disposable.

Comment: @Alex, yes, it is. It derives from [ClientRuntimeContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientruntimecontext.aspx), which implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi sorry, it was a MSVS error, it shows that it doesn't implement IDisposable if `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Runtime` is not referenced.

Comment: check below for the correct answer if you are using SharePoint online: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80961/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-403-forbidden/80964#80964

Comment: How can i prompt the end user with supplying the username and password in a secret manner. i dont want to hardcode the username, password in the .cs file.

Comment: @SaMolPP Use `SecureString` with the `.Append` property to take the password in as user input via some prompt or modal.