# ASP.NET ADFS authentication to access sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, adfs

I want to build an application to access sharepoint website. First I have created a login form..

- I want to authenticate via ADFS How to do that from my website.
- How to access the sharepoint utilities after logged in.

That's it. I just want to show the files/documents at my website.

Please share me links or sample if any one have. If available in MVC then no problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to display SharePoint List/Library data in your own application/website, so in this scenario, there are two approaches:

**Approach 1**

Use RSS feeds to embed SharePoint Data into your Application/Website. You can use any RSS Feed viewer for your application.

**Approach 2**

You can use SharePoint Client Object Model (CSOM). Using CSOM you can get data from SharePoint Environment and use the data to embed in your application.

Here is a reference link to get familiar with CSOM : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx

Hope these details will help you.

Comment: Approach 2 is good, btw I didn't found login process, how to achieve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382583/use-credentials-to-interact-with-the-client-object-model-of-sharepoint  Please have a look at this link. It will let you know that how you can use credentials and you can setup authentication to get data using Client Object Model.

Comment: hi @HemantKabra, i know this thread is old. i have managed to implement  it on locally using approach 2. however, when i port over to the server i am getting errors. do u have any advice for me?